# What is the origin of "Gudi Padwa"?

Tags: festivals, celebrations

In Maharashtra, the New Year is celebrated with a holiday called Gudi Padwa.  I had heard dark history behind it and I became speechless.  So what's the truth behind Gudi Padwa?

Comment: It's truth I known It's true history which known organisation Sambhaji Brigade told and studied.  Check it out [1](http://mulniwasikhobragade.blogspot.in/2013/04/gudi-padwa-sambhaji-maharaj-murder-mar.html) [2](http://old.bamcef.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50:dark-history-of-gudi-padwa-&catid=31:news-that-matters)

Comment: why dont you include that dark history in the question ?

Comment: I didn't downvoted it but it make no sense without elaborating that dark history

Comment: Dark history is in my answer. What is dark history I explained in answer not in question. I want to let people know true history and what they following like cowherd.

Comment: I'm really afraid you all guys considering my provided source is wrong, totally wrong and even I also got that all of you are not accepting truth. Even I let you know on the basis of **manusmrithi verse 125** My provided source is authentic because those organisations are studied and researched that's it. You guys wouldn't accept because you are Brhamins and I'm so sorry If I've hurt you with posting this. I'll delete if all of you want to. But I'm afraid that theres no place for truth. Sorry at all.

Comment: @Swapnil I'm not Brahmin by birth but i'm pretty much sure you don't know meaning of Brahmin. Don't mix Varna and Caste.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Whether I mixed up varna or caste?

Comment: @Swapnil Gudi Padwa is ancient hindu new year, it is celebrated with various names in various regions of India and has absolutely nothing to do with Dharmaveer Sambhaji. In Telugu and Kannada areas it is called Ugadi, In manipur it is called Meetei Cheiraoba, In Sindh Cheti Chand, In north India chaitra navratri, Rajasthan and Haryana it called Thapna. It is celebrated even in Bali, hindu island in Indonesia. http://zeenews.india.com/india/as-india-celebrated-navratri-hindus-of-bali-observed-day-of-silence-1991035.html?src=fb There is no conspiracy against beloved leader Sambhaji.

Comment: Festival celebrated by region on the occasion of new year but in Maharashtra it wouldn't be. In which region they puts pot on bamboo stick? Is it considered auspicious?

Comment: @swapnil you need to put @ before username of person you are replying to in your comment. Otherwise person you are replying to won't get notification. Each region has particular customs associated with new year. Ugadi has tradition eating neem and jaggery. Bali Hindus have tradition of day of silence. With ancient enough festival, various unique tradition gets attached. For example modern marathis have started new custom of "shobhayatras" on gudi padwa day.  After 200 yrs people will wonder why and how this tradition started. It is just another way to celebrate.

Comment: @swapnil I have never heard of pot or neem or saree being inauspicious. How can  saree be inauspicious? We wear it everyday. We gift it on diwali and during weddings. Neem is believed to be medicinal. Anyway gudi is raised to celebrate victory of shalivahana King over sakas. It was done by people of paithan because he used pots of sticks to fool saka army into thinking he has much more soldiers than he actually did and thus successfully demoralise them and defeat them.

Comment: @Aks [Here is why it wouldn't be auspicious](http://mulniwasikhobragade.blogspot.in/2013/04/gudi-padwa-sambhaji-maharaj-murder-mar.html)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Gudi Padwa was first celebrated in 1689 after the killing of Chatrapati
Sambhaji Raje. Why?**

*Gudipadva* is auspicious day for western Maharashtrian Hindu. *Gudi* is
sort of flag comprises *bambu*, *saree*, *neem* branches, inverted *lota* all
inauspicious things to hindus. Still it is proudly flagged high on their
houses. This gudi which is made from inauspicious things to hindus has been flagged
high since the death of Chatrapati Sambhaji Raje by the Aurangjeb's Brahmin
ministers at Vadhu-Budruk. For the high class of Maharashtrians it was the
happiest moments in their life, it was a victory for them as Mahant Athavale
of Sanatan says, "Gudi is symbol of victory". Why Brahmin minister's killed
Sambhaji Raje? Because

1. Raje had killed four ministers who had betrayed him, withdrew
   their *sanad *and *vatan*(donated land and authority)
2. Sambhaji Raje had written ***Budhbhushanam*** sanskrit granth (*Manusmriti
   says only Brahmins can study sanskirt and has refused other castes to study
   sanskrit, if Shudra listen, read, write sanskrit, he will have to face
   punishment*)
3. Religious reformation in Maharashtra was started by Raje.

All these movements were revolt against Hindu religious establishments.

> Note: Can found same reference in the book **"[Shivaji Rajanche Khare Shatru Kon?"](https://cdn.satyashodhak.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/shivrayanche-khare-shatru.pdf)** of Shiv Shrimant Kokate. page no. 43

That providing information that Aurangjeba didn't killed Sambhaji Raje because of religion it just because political reason.

And for kind information it isn't anti-Brahmin because who else claiming that weren't against Brahmin but their violence that they committing through Manusmriti. And as their precepts. Guys considering I'm spreading poison it isn't true.

> You must read **Historiography** wiki([Shivaji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivaji)) document it's also authenticate and that is also proving that isn't anti-Brahmin.

And so it is thinkable why considerable anti-Brahmin organizations support  honorable Narendra Dabholkar when he was Brahmin?

That isn't what you guys thinking. It feels bitter as poison because truth is always bitter.

Concern is not to celebrate what isn't truth, isn't prideful and it's not our festival truly.

Comment: You copied content from [this site](http://old.bamcef.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=50:dark-history-of-gudi-padwa-&catid=31:news-that-matters) but didn't cite it. Plagiarism is not allowed. Anyways, only authentic scripures (sources) are allowed on this site. Answer citing random blogs will be deleted.

Comment: "Manusmriti says only Brahmins can study sanskirt and has refused other castes to study sanskrit," Can you show me where this is present in Manusmriti? Here is [the link](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi#contents) for Manusmriti.

Comment: Thos organisations studying with help of authentic proof. If you'd help find out authentic  source to answer my question. Even people better know about these organisations.

Comment: Sabhaji Raje was murdered by this verse.

Comment: सङ्करापात्रकृत्यासु मासं शोधनमैन्दवम् ।
मलिनीकरणीयेषु तप्तः स्याद् यावकैस्त्र्यहम् ॥ १२५ ॥

saṅkarāpātrakṛtyāsu māsaṃ śodhanamaindavam |
malinīkaraṇīyeṣu taptaḥ syād yāvakaistryaham || 125 ||

In the case of acts conducive to the degradation of ‘caste-mixture,’ or of those that make one unworthy of receiving gifts, purification is secured by the monthly lunar penance; and in the case of those that lead to defilement, one should mortify his body on barley-products for three days.—(125)

Comment: My provided source is authentic.

Comment: When in early time other casts wouldn't allow to read Veda. Because of this they weren't allow to read sanskrit. That's it. Its clear but I know I got you would never accept truth and true history.

Comment: @@Swapnil..Its not about Sanskrit ..its about the Vedas..Sudras can read and hear the Puranas which are also  in the Sanskrit language..

Comment: So does my provided source totally wrong?

Comment: First of all, know difference between Varna and Caste and let's speak about complete history (not just 18th or 19th century). See [caste system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/caste-system?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) related questions on this site.

Comment: Swapnil, im from goa and prety well versed with history of shivaji nd samvhaji maharaj. These r all fabricated stories of pro anti brahmin organizations. Please dont fall for them. And manu smriti dsnt say anythng about sambhaji maharaj.and im v well aware of agenda of sambhaji brigade. All their activities nd entire ideology is anti social and anti ethical. Dont spread poison here.

Comment: Well that true history corrupted and that's why you thinking I'm trying to spreading myth. Obviously manismriti isn't say but deed by 125 verse.   Refer my link I've gave. It isn't anti-ethical it is about what/how true history is corrupted. That's it and so no would want to accept truth.

Comment: @Swapnil Cite History books as authentic reference not some random sites. Moreover, it will be better if you cite mythlogical reasons for this question from Scriptures such as Puranas. You can even  cite stories of Shivaji Maharaj and samvhaji from authentic sources. **Only authentic sources are allowed on this site**. Else, this answer will be deleted.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yeah I know authentic but it is true, history is changed and corrupted. People don't know what was it really and I'm afraid about it.

Comment: @Swapnil As a moderator, i'm not talking about authenticity of content you posted. But as per site rules, one must cite only authentic sources. You can cite any book (by eminent Historian) which says the same. As per site rules, answers citing random websites or answers with no sources will be deleted.

Comment: @TheDestroyer It's not random those organisations are studying and then claimed. But for authenticity I'll provide source to prove that my answer isn't any wrong. Thanks

Comment: @Swapnil As per site policy, unsourced answers will be deleted. Edit this answer with authentic sources and flag to undelete it.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Yeah they were pure Kshatriyas so no question of any bramhinical revolt against them. They had a birth right to rule and they did, by Hindavi Swarajya.

Comment: @ Swapnil Gudi Padwa is celebrated as a common (standard season) New year start in Maharashtra, Andhra and Karnataka. Actually Gudi translates as Temple.